# Does a user lose their rep association bonus if their rep drops below 200?

Tags: support, association-bonus

My understanding is that when a user has 200 rep on an account, any accounts they have/subsequently create get a 100 rep bonus.

What are the ramifications if the account with over 200 rep then drops below 200 rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the association bonus doesn't get retracted.